# C# function for removing attributes in HTML

Tags: c#, html

I have some html content who have some classes and inline stylesheet. i want a c# function who return the content by removing all attributes from them like

```
<div class="blah blah1 blah2" id="info" style="">it is content</div>
```

return

```
<div>it is content</div>
```

I want to do this in c# using regex.

how i can do this in c#

Comment: Easiest way would be to use regular expressions to do this.

Comment: @Chevex I almost want to upvote that but I'm afraid to just in case you aren't joking...

Comment: What? I wasn't joking, it really is the best way. Click for proof: http://www.u413.com/pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: this is nonsense to do a task by adding a third patry comp when can be done by a regex

Comment: This is not nonsense, if you want to do it properly, do not use Regex.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags